# How can I apply time difference between 2 TIMESTAMPS in SQL/Impala?

Tags: sql, impala

I have two columns (both TIMESTAMPS as value)

```
start date          | end date
2017-11-29 19:45:00 | 2017-11-29 20:13:00
```

I want to see the difference in minutes.

I've tried

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('end date') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('start date') as mindiff
```

but that did not work.

How can I do this in SQL / Impala

Comment: What does "that did not work" mean?  It *should* give the difference in seconds...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the mistake.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('end date') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('start date') as mindiff
```

the quotes sees it as a text (actually manually fill the date)
but for mentioning the columns I need to remove the ''.

So it should be

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start date) as mindiff
```